# XSS Permanent Cross-site scripting vulnerability?

Tags: php, xss

I'm running vulnerability software against my PHP code and its obsessed with this page, which is an update cart page.  Its fairly straight forward just checking for coupon codes and I reckon quite locked down but its claiming that its a XSS Permanent Cross-site scripting vulnerability.

Can anybody advise whether it is or not, I've looked at it for so long now and changed a few things with no success, that I've gone code blind now and can't see if I've missed anything.

Cheers

```
<?php
include_once ('db_access.php');
require_once ('htmlpurifier.standalone.php');

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Cache.DefinitionImpl', null);     // Disable caching of HTML Purifier

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

$coupon_data = get_coupon();                    // Get Coupon details   

session_start();

unset ($_SESSION['coupon']);

if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $qty)
{

$clean_id = $purifier->purify($_POST[$id]);                                 // id passed from form

    if($clean_id <= '0')        // Down to Quantity zero so remove from cart
    {
    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);          // Clear Cart
    unset($_SESSION['coupon']);             // Clear Coupon
    unset($_SESSION['msg_'.$id]);          // Clear Custom Message      

    } else {

        if (is_numeric($clean_id)) {

        $coupon = $purifier->purify($_POST['coupon']);      // Coupon code as entered

        $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = $clean_id;                 // Quantity

        $coupon = strtoupper($coupon);                      // Coupon Code from form

        $known_disc_coupon = strtoupper($coupon_data['0']['coupon_name']);          // Discount coupon
        $known_del_coupon = strtoupper($coupon_data['1']['coupon_name']);           // Delivery coupon

        if (( $coupon_data['0']['enabled'] == '1') && ($coupon == $known_disc_coupon)) {                ## Coupon for discount is enabled
        $_SESSION['coupon'] = 'DISCOUNT';
        }

        if (( $coupon_data['1']['enabled'] == '1') && ($coupon == $known_del_coupon)) {                 ## Coupon for delivery is enabled
        $_SESSION['coupon'] = 'DELIVERY';
        }   
        }
    }
}
}
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
$mysource = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
header('Location:' . $mysource);
exit;
} else {
header('Location:index.php');
exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't use HTML Purifier.  It doesn't make sense in this context.  You only need to HTML purifier if you're expecting HTML.  Otherwise, treat data you get as text and convert from there.  There is nothing clean about your `$clean_id`.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the way you use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. It has nothing to do with XSS, but it' still an unvalidated redirect (which can be a vulnerability under certain circumstances). The software is probably not smart enough to figure that out, and just freaks out when it sees `$_POST` :). Rather than using such software, try to understand how could an attacker exploit your app

Comment: Ah ok... though I started off with this;$clean_id = (filter_var($_POST[$id], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));   # Quantity